# Recover signal from its power spectral density

Tags: power-spectral-density

I was wondering whether we can recover a signal $x(t)$ from its power spectral density using signal processing techniques.

Comment: This is a phase retrieval problem.

Answer (score 4):

Generally (in the absence of prior knowledge) , I don't think this could be done.

The PSD is the absolute value  squared of the DFT of the signal, and the abs function is not 1-to-1. For example abs(x) could be produced by f=x and f=-x.

However, if you have some prior knowledge about the signal then you could reconstruct it from the PSD. Without more knowledge of what you're trying to do I don't think I could help you.

Comment: The PSD is _not_ the absolute value of the DFT of the signal, it is the **squared magnitude;** not $|X[k]|$ but $|X[k]|^2$. But the conclusion that the signal cannot be recovered from the PSD (or its iDFT the autocorrelation function) is correct. See, for example, [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/10686/235) for why the attempt via autocorrelation fails.

Comment: Note that for the special case of audio, where human hearing is mostly insensitive to phase information, you may be able to generate a reasonable approximation of the original signal such that a human listener will not be able to tell the difference between the approximation and the original.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out by making up a `N=2` signal, `X`, e.g. (matlab) `X = [2 3]';` and then doing its sample autocorrelation by hand. I used Marple's 1987 text. Then I did `N=3` version and `N=4` and saw the pattern.

Here's matlab code to do it

```
clear all;  
close all;  
Xm(:,1) = [3 1 4 6 9 3 6 1 2 -55 6 3]'; %original signal  
N = length(Xm(:,1));  
mu = sum(Xm(:,1))/N; % get the sample mean  

var = 0;  
for i=1:N  
  var = var + (Xm(i,1)-mu)^2;  
end  
var = var / N; % get the sample variance  

% first col of X has the adjusted signal, and we'll put our recovered X in
% the second column so they're easy to compare.

X(:,1) = Xm(:,1) - mu;  
R = autocorr(X(:,1), N-1);  

C = R * var; % this is the denormalized autocovariance.  
M = triu(toeplitz(X(:,1))); % C = MX (the first col of X, actually)  

X(:,2) = N*inv(M)*C;  
Xrec = X(:,2)+mu; % this is the recovered Xm.
```